# Display picklist field in lightning component throwing error

Tags: apex, lightning-aura-components, lightning, lightning-experience

I have designed a lightning component to fetch record details. I am having this lightning component in the record detail page. I am also having picklist field inside the component. When I simply place picklist field inside component and try to fetch and display picklist values inside the component its working.

```
      <aura:attribute name="recordId" type="String" default="{!v.recordId}"/> 
     <aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.doInit}"/>
      <aura:attribute name="myObject" type="String" default=""/>
   <aura:attribute name="objInfo" type="case" default="{sobjectType : 'Case'}" />
 <div id="gee" class="slds slds-scrollable--x">

   <ui:inputSelect aura:id="cirjustification" class="slds-select" label="" value="{!v.myObject.CIRJustification__c}"/> 
<lightning:button variant="brand" label="Submit" onclick="{!c.myAction}" />
 </div>
```

But if I add lightning tabset to the code, I am getting apex error.

```
  <lightning:tabset >
  <lightning:tab label="Main">    
  <div id="gee" class="slds slds-scrollable--x">
   <ui:inputSelect aura:id="cirjustification" class="slds-select" label="" value="{!v.myObject.CIRJustification__c}"/> 
<lightning:button variant="brand" label="Submit" onclick="{!c.myAction}" />
 </div>
   </lightning:tab>
</lightning:tabset>
```

Error : [image]
I can find that the error is because the value cannot be set properly, but don't know how to do this. Can anyone help?

My controller code

```
({

 doInit: function(component, event, helper) {
    helper.fetchPickListVal(component, 'CIRJustification__c', 'cirjustification');
}
})
```

Helper code

```
({
fetchPickListVal: function(component, fieldName, elementId) {
    var action = component.get("c.getselectOptions");
    action.setParams({
        "objObject": component.get("v.objInfo"),
        "fld": fieldName
    });
    var opts = [];
    action.setCallback(this, function(response) {
        if (response.getState() == "SUCCESS") {
            var allValues = response.getReturnValue();

            if (allValues != undefined && allValues.length > 0) {
                opts.push({
                    class: "optionClass",
                    label: "--- None ---",
                    value: ""
                });
            }
            for (var i = 0; i < allValues.length; i++) {
                opts.push({
                    class: "optionClass",
                    label: allValues[i],
                    value: allValues[i]
                });
            }
            component.find(elementId).set("v.options", opts);
        }
    });
    $A.enqueueAction(action);
},
```

})

Apex class

```
@AuraEnabled
  public static List < String > getselectOptions(sObject objObject, string fld) {
system.debug('objObject --->' + objObject);
 system.debug('fld --->' + fld);
 List < String > allOpts = new list < String > ();
 // Get the object type of the SObject.
Schema.sObjectType objType = objObject.getSObjectType();

// Describe the SObject using its object type.
Schema.DescribeSObjectResult objDescribe = objType.getDescribe();

// Get a map of fields for the SObject
map < String, Schema.SObjectField > fieldMap = objDescribe.fields.getMap();

// Get the list of picklist values for this field.
list < Schema.PicklistEntry > values =
 fieldMap.get(fld).getDescribe().getPickListValues();

// Add these values to the selectoption list.
for (Schema.PicklistEntry a: values) {
 allOpts.add(a.getValue());
}
system.debug('allOpts ---->' + allOpts);
allOpts.sort();
return allOpts;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

`Lightning:tab` component creates its body during runtime. You won’t be able to reference the component during initialization or afterender. You can set your content using value binding with component attributes instead.

**example:**

**component:**

```
<aura:component>
    <aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.doInit}"/>
    <aura:attribute name="options" type="list"/>
    <lightning:tabset >
        <lightning:tab label="Main">    
            <div id="gee" class="slds slds-scrollable--x">
                <ui:inputSelect aura:id="cirjustification" class="slds-select" label="" value="a1">
                    <aura:iteration items="{!v.options}" var="opt">
                        <ui:inputSelectOption text="{!opt.label}" label="{!opt.label}" value="{!opt.value}"/>
                    </aura:iteration>
                </ui:inputSelect>
                <lightning:button variant="brand" label="Submit" onclick="{!c.myAction}" />
            </div>
        </lightning:tab>
    </lightning:tabset>
</aura:component>
```

Controller:

```
 doInit: function(component, event, helper) {
         var opts = [];

    opts.push({
        class: "optionClass",
        label: "--- None ---",
        value: ""
    });
    for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        opts.push({
            class: "optionClass",
            label:'a'+i,
            value: 'a'+i
        });
    }
    component.set("v.options", opts);
    }
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/72563/discussion-on-answer-by-vignesh-display-picklist-field-in-lightning-component-th).